# Python issue with finding given string in list of letters

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to figure out how to find if the elements of a list equal a given string?

```
lists=["a","b",'c']
str1='abc'
```

I know it is probably easy, but I am having a hard time without using string methods.

Thanks, 
         DD

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l == list('abc')
True
```

But, if the order of items in the list can be arbitrary, you can use sets:

```
>>> l = ['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> set(l) == set('abc')
True
```

or:

```
>>> l = ['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> s = set(l)
>>> all(c in s for c in 'abc')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lists=["a","b",'c']
>>> str1='abc'
>>> ''.join(lists) == str1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .join to create a string from your list:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
strToComapre = ''.join(list1)
```

Now you can check if strToComapre  is "in" the original str:

```
if strToCompare in originalStr:
    print "yes!"
```

If you want a pure compare use:

```
if strToCompare == originalStr:
    print "yes! it's pure!"
```

There are lots of options in python i'll add some other useful posts:

[Compare string with all values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783969/compare-string-with-all-values-in-array)

http://www.decalage.info/en/python/print_list

Comment: Don't compare strings using `is`. Sometimes it works thanks to string interning, but `==` is what really works.

Comment: You are right, the post was edited 'is' will do the trick for identities in a simple compare '==' its the best to use.