# How to check a txt contain all the element in a list?

Tags: python, string

Like I have a text file and read it already using

```
with open(full_path,'r') as f2:
    contents = f2.read()
```

content like:
    `sadasdasdasdsa dasdasdasdffsdf  [sdas] aaa dfdsfdsfdfds bbb`

and I have a list like:

```
a = ['aaa','bbb']
b = ['343242','bbb']
```

We could see all element in list`a` are in `content`,elements in `b`  are not all in `content`.   but how could I check it in a loop? Like if a in content print `ok` else print `not`.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use in operator to check for substrings. Then you can use loops for check for the conditions you want to fill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare string with all values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783969/compare-string-with-all-values-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
ct='sadasdasdasdsa dasdasdasdffsdf  [sdas] aaa dfdsfdsfdfds bbb'
a = ['aaa','bbb']
b = ['343242','bbb']

flag=True
for i in a:
    if i not in ct:
        flag=False
for i in b:
    if i in ct:
        flag=False
if flag:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: I mean element in `b` are not all in `content`.because of `343242` sorry, its my bad